# Why recursion "stops"?

Tags: c, recursion, boolean

I'm trying to understand recursion.
My teacher wrote this program to determine whether a string is a palindrome or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 80

bool palindrome( const char * const sPtr ); // prototype
bool palindromeKernel(const char * const sPtr, size_t l, size_t r);

int main( void ) {
   char sentence[ SIZE ]; 
   puts( "Enter a line of text:" );

   fgets( sentence, SIZE, stdin );

   puts( "\nIs the line palindrome?" );

   if ( palindrome( sentence )) printf("yes");
   else printf("no");
   putchar('\n');
    } 

bool palindrome( const char * const sPtr ){
   size_t len = strlen(sPtr);
   return(palindromeKernel(sPtr, 0, len-2)); 
}

bool palindromeKernel(const char * const sPtr, size_t l, size_t r){
   puts("1");
   if (l >= r) return true;
   return ((sPtr[l] == sPtr[r]) && palindromeKernel(sPtr, l+1, r-1));
}
```

I added a `printf` statement to check when the `palindromeKernel` is called. When I input a palindrome it works as I expect:

```
Output 1
Enter a line of text:
mrowlatemymetalworm

Is the line palindrome?
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
yes
```

Here the function is called 10 times, and I understand why. What I don't understand is this:

```
mtowlatemymetalworm

Is the line palindrome?
1
1
no
```

The string is not a palindrome (I modified the second character).
Here the function is called 2 times, so from what I understand it stops calling itself when it returns false.
Why?

EDIT

Alright thank you so much.
but now I have another doubt.

But if I invert the order of the last return, like this:

```
return (palindromeKernel(sPtr, l+1, r-1) && (sPtr[l]==sPtr[r]));
```

the program still works
How so?
I don't really understand how a recursive function work inside an if condition

Comment: Because `&&` performs short-circuiting. When `(sPtr[l] == sPtr[r])` is false, it doesn't make the recursive call after `&&`.

Comment: when you reversed it, it prints `1` ten times right? because the recursive call comes first, it will have to recurse *before* any short-circuiting can occur. it will then evaluate `true`/`false` as it is exiting each function call. you definitely should get the same result (`&&` is an associative operation), but it may get that result a slightly different way, as you've seen

Comment: Yes, it prints 1 ten times.
But i don't fully understand the if condition behaviour
How does it evaluate true false if the function is called ten times?

Comment: As mentioned above and un my answer, the function is not called then times if the test fails early. In C, "if (a && big_complex_function()) ..." will not call big_complex_function() if a is false, because it already knows that the combined expression will be false.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
return ((sPtr[l] == sPtr[r]) && palindromeKernel(sPtr, l+1, r-1));
```

is the trick. C has what's called "short-circuit evaluation" of && and ||, so if the first leg of an && expression is false, it does not need to evaluate the second and does not, so when the two characters compared to not match (sPtr[l] == sPtr[r] is false), then it stops calling itself recursively and just returns false.

Comment: More specifically, returns false.